Which manga chapter does Nejimaki Seirei Senki's anime end in?
Which manga chapter does Nejimaki Seirei Senki's anime end in?

Could you clarify "season" in this context? Did you mean to compare the last episode of the anime adaptation with the manga volume/chapter?

Yes the last episode of the anime adaptation with the mangas chapter
